# Getting TypeError: 'list' object is not callable when setting index in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, set

I have simple Pandas Dataframe:

```
data.head(5)


> Date  Time    Open    High    Low Close   Vol OI
> 0 02/02/1993  16:00   44.23   44.38   44.13   44.34   201300  0
> 1 02/03/1993  16:00   44.41   44.84   44.38   44.82   529400  0
> 2 02/04/1993  16:00   44.97   45.10   44.88   45.00   531500  0
> 3 02/05/1993  16:00   44.97   45.06   44.73   44.97   492100  0
> 4 02/08/1993  16:00   44.97   45.13   44.92   44.98   596100  0
```

I want to set Column "Date" as index:

```
data.set_index('Date')
```

But get error "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-a610da45b82c> in <module>()
----> 1 data.set_index('Date')

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Currently the index in data is RangeIndex:

```
data.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5873, step=1)
```

Any tip why I cannot set the index using Date column?

Thank you.

Comment: What does `data['Date'].iloc[0]` show? can you post also `data.info()` output also `data.columns.tolist()`

Comment: Please include the full traceback in cases like these.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue of "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" when using the set_index command. I got the solution by first calling 'reindex()' method and then using set_index. Hope it works for you.
Aamir

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add parameter `inplace=True` to [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Another solution is:

```
data = data.set_index('Date')
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'High': {0: 44.380000000000003, 1: 44.840000000000003, 2: 45.100000000000001, 3: 45.060000000000002, 4: 45.130000000000003}, 'Vol': {0: 201300, 1: 529400, 2: 531500, 3: 492100, 4: 596100}, 'Close': {0: 44.340000000000003, 1: 44.82, 2: 45.0, 3: 44.969999999999999, 4: 44.979999999999997}, 'Date': {0: '02/02/1993', 1: '02/03/1993', 2: '02/04/1993', 3: '02/05/1993', 4: '02/08/1993'}, 'Open': {0: 44.229999999999997, 1: 44.409999999999997, 2: 44.969999999999999, 3: 44.969999999999999, 4: 44.969999999999999}, 'Time': {0: '16:00', 1: '16:00', 2: '16:00', 3: '16:00', 4: '16:00'}, 'Low': {0: 44.130000000000003, 1: 44.380000000000003, 2: 44.880000000000003, 3: 44.729999999999997, 4: 44.920000000000002}, 'OI': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}})
print (data)

#   Close        Date   High    Low  OI   Open   Time     Vol
#0  44.34  02/02/1993  44.38  44.13   0  44.23  16:00  201300
#1  44.82  02/03/1993  44.84  44.38   0  44.41  16:00  529400
#2  45.00  02/04/1993  45.10  44.88   0  44.97  16:00  531500
#3  44.97  02/05/1993  45.06  44.73   0  44.97  16:00  492100
#4  44.98  02/08/1993  45.13  44.92   0  44.97  16:00  596100

print (data.columns)
#Index(['Close', 'Date', 'High', 'Low', 'OI', 'Open', 'Time', 'Vol'], dtype='object')


data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
print (data)

#            Close   High    Low  OI   Open   Time     Vol
#Date                                                     
#02/02/1993  44.34  44.38  44.13   0  44.23  16:00  201300
#02/03/1993  44.82  44.84  44.38   0  44.41  16:00  529400
#02/04/1993  45.00  45.10  44.88   0  44.97  16:00  531500
#02/05/1993  44.97  45.06  44.73   0  44.97  16:00  492100
#02/08/1993  44.98  45.13  44.92   0  44.97  16:00  596100
```

If need set index and convert to datetime in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) use (if separator is `,` you can omit it, because by default `sep=','`):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Date;Time;Open;High;Low;Close;Vol;OI
02/02/1993;16:00;44.23;44.38;44.13;44.34;201300;0
02/03/1993;16:00;44.41;44.84;44.38;44.82;529400;0
02/04/1993;16:00;44.97;45.10;44.88;45.00;531500;0
02/05/1993;16:00;44.97;45.06;44.73;44.97;492100;0
02/08/1993;16:00;44.97;45.13;44.92;44.98;596100;0"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col='Date', parse_dates=['Date'])
print (data)

             Time   Open   High    Low  Close     Vol  OI
Date                                                     
1993-02-02  16:00  44.23  44.38  44.13  44.34  201300   0
1993-02-03  16:00  44.41  44.84  44.38  44.82  529400   0
1993-02-04  16:00  44.97  45.10  44.88  45.00  531500   0
1993-02-05  16:00  44.97  45.06  44.73  44.97  492100   0
1993-02-08  16:00  44.97  45.13  44.92  44.98  596100   0
```

Comment: This doesnot help in this case. Still getting "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

Comment: Ok, what is `print (data.columns)` ?

Comment: And what is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: `data['Date'].iloc[0]` shows `'02/02/1993'`
`data.info()`is:`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5873 entries, 0 to 5872
Data columns (total 8 columns):
Date     5873 non-null object
Time     5873 non-null object
Open     5873 non-null float64
High     5873 non-null float64
Low      5873 non-null float64
Close    5873 non-null float64
Vol      5873 non-null int64
OI       5873 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(4), int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 367.1+ KB`

Comment: Very interesting. If convert `to datetime` column `Date` by `data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])` before `set_index` in your real data, it work?

Comment: Even after converting I get the same TypeError 'list' object is not callable.
Date is: Date     5873 non-null datetime64[ns]

Comment: Data are from csv, excel? What is print (pd.show_versions())

Comment: pd.show is (shorted): INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.5.1.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows


pandas: 0.18.1
nose: 1.3.7
pip: 8.1.1
setuptools: 20.7.0
Cython: 0.23.4
numpy: 1.11.0
scipy: 0.17.0
statsmodels: 0.6.1
xarray: None
IPython: 4.0.3
sphinx: 1.3.1
patsy: 0.4.0
dateutil: 2.5.3
pytz: 2016.4
blosc: None

xlsxwriter: 0.8.4
lxml: 3.5.0
bs4: 4.4.1
boto: 2.39.0
pandas_datareader: 0.2.1
None


Yes, data are from csv. I will try to set index directly in import. I was just interested why I cannot set index in this stage.

Comment: It is really interesting. You can set in `read_csv` `index_col=['Date']`

Comment: So, I dont know if I help you. Good luck! I dont know if is possible test it in another PC or reinstall pandas.

Comment: Can I delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have used `.to_list()` method in the code
I used same method and was getting error again and again. So make sure to use `set_index` method before it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I tried the solutions of the other answers but they wouldn't work for me.
(re-indexing, setting in-place=true, or assigning to another variable)

I was using jupyter-lab, and **what did work for me was restarting all the variables from the kernel**. Maybe if you were also using notebooks, that'd fix it for you too.

If i had to guess, my index somehow got corrupted along my attempts, and thats why resetting the kernel fixed it, and it might be the same for you.

Leaving it here for future reference, hope it helps.